# Making route unique to one ejs file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, ejs

i want a URL like this `localhost3000/hh234due`, with a unique id, to route to specific page, but with what am doing it is conflicting with other routes.

how to make /:id unique to one view

```
    module.exports = function (app) {

        app.get('/:id', function (req, res) {
            res.render('page/index');
        });  

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since routes are tested in order, place it **last** in the sequence and anything it would conflict with will take precedence over it.

Answer (score 0):

In general, this is just a questionable practice because

```
app.get('/:id', ...)
```

matches every single possible top level route and invites conflicts with other top level routes that you want/need in the workings of your site.

You can make it work by always placing it as the last possible route definition, but I would recommend changing the URL to something like

```
http://localhost:3000/id/hh234due
```

and then you can use:

```
app.get('/id/:id', ...)
```

and not have any conflicts with any of your other top level routes.

When doing it this way, the URL structure is more declarative too since the `/id` part clearly states what this URL is rather than before where you were more relying on the fact that it doesn't look like any of the other top level routes on your site so "I guess" it must be an id which is not as declarative or clear to the other developers that might work on this site some time in the future.

Comment: what about when creating a 404 page

Comment: and all your routes are arranged in different folders

Comment: @coder - I don't understand either of those comments.  I'm suggesting you use `http://localhost:3000/id/hh234due` as the URL and `app.get('/id/:id', ...)` as the route definition which has absolutely nothing to do with a 404 page or routes in folders.  You can do whatever you want with a 404 page or routes in folders as that has nothing to do with my answer (or your question).

Comment: @coder - If you have a different question about a 404 page or routes in folder, then after you finish this question by accepting an answer (clicking the checkmark to the left of an answer that answers your question), you can ask a more specific question about one of those other subjects.  Or, if you think it is related to this question, then please clarify how.

Answer (score -1):

It should be enough to put the spcific page routing before the general one, like this:

```
module.exports = function (app) {

    app.get('/hh234due', function (req, res) {
        res.render('<your special page>');
    }); 

    app.get('/:id', function (req, res) {
        res.render('page/index');
    });  

}
```